# Flutter how create new project with ordinary package name?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In android studio 4.2, the interface for creating projects for flutter was changed. For example create a new project named `com.example` but in the final file `AndroidManifest.xml` we have a package for some reason called `com.example.example` redundant part appears. `Organization` field must be of two parts, there you cannot just enter `com` to get the output `com.example` I understand that this is not a problem for most, you can simply create a name from three parts, but it was convenient before and there was no such problem.

Found [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) This way works, but I would like a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio asks for your organisation and project name differently and combines them to make your app's package name. For example if your enter your organisation as `com` and project name as `example`, your package name would be created as `com.example`.
In your case you are entering the organisation as `com.example` and project name as `example`. So, it sets `com.example.example` as app's package name.

Package Name = Organisation + Project Name

Comment: I understand what's going on, but now I can't create a short name for my application like abc.xyz only abc.xyz.xyz

Comment: If you want your package name to be `abc.xyz`, set your organisation to `abc` and project name as `xyz`.

Comment: Invalid module name: 'xyz.' - must be a valid Dart package name (lower_case_with_underscores).

Comment: Can you share the code or screenshot where the error occurs?